# Decrypt message using bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The first input line is an encoded message, and the second line is the key integer number. Convert the key to two bytes and sum up its items. Then add the resulting sum to the code point of each character in the message. Finally, print the decoded message.

So we have message: `HlAdghmcXnt`

And key: `256`

So I started with:

```
int_to_bytes = sum(int(input()).to_bytes(2, 'little'))
sum(int_to_bytes)
```

But how to add this sum of bytes to each character of message?

Comment: Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: @Tomerikoo  i do, i have to loop for every char ? but how to add sum to char? (thats the main question honestly :) )

Comment: Maybe [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) might help

Comment: @Tomerikoo can you show some example ? using chr and ord in loop?

Comment: `''.join([chr(ord(i) + sum(int_to_bytes)) for i in s])`

Comment: `'ImBehindYou'` lol, Kappa take care

Comment: @Epsi95  var s stands for?

Comment: `s = "HlAdghmcXnt"`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh god, thanks a lot. Need to relax a bit

Comment: How to attach an solution and close it?

Comment: I rolled back your edit; your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to post an answer of your own, please feel encouraged to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're summing one time too many.

`int_to_bytes = sum(int(input()).to_bytes(2, 'little'))` is the sum of the two bytes, in this case `1`. Because `256 = b'00000001_00000000'`.

Now you need to:

- Iterate over each character of the string.
- Get its code number (using [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)).
- Add the sum above.
- Convert back to a character (using [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)):

```py
s = "HlAdghmcXnt"
key = 256

int_to_bytes = sum(key.to_bytes(2, 'little'))

for c in s:
    print(chr(ord(c) + int_to_bytes), end="")
```

Gives:

```
ImBehindYou
```